# Double Activity definition when using dynamic modules

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have this project structure on a test app.

App module -> an API interfaces module -> a dynamic module that implements my API interfaces and used third party APIs.

On the dynamic module I have an `Activity` defined from a third party. This activity has a check in it to make sure no other app in the entire system has the same `scheme` registered. Basically to make not two apps are using the same third party API key.

Their code for this check is super simple:

```
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setData(Uri.parse("theirscheme://....."));
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, 0);
```

When using dynamic modules with the code above, `activities` has a size of `2`.

I managed to get `activities` to have a size of `1` by using `Edit configuration` on Android Studio and unchecking the dynamic module on the General tab. But then the module wasn't installed so I couldn't access it.

I don't know what will happen once I do use `SplitManager` to install it, will I once again have a double activity?

My only solution right now has been to put the `Activity` in the `App module` manifest and only there but that is not a good permanent solution.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to handle this situation?

Thanks.

Edit: I've tried several Android phones with various versions (6,7,10,11) and only the phones with Android 10 seem to have the issue. So maybe it is an Android 10 issue?

Edit: I have made a simple sample showing the issue: https://github.com/casolorz/doubleactivityissue

I even tested it on the Android 10 emulator. It will display a count of 2 if it has the issue. A count of 1 if it doesn't.

I think this is probably a bug, but I don't know if I should submit it to the bug tracker of Android Studio? Android? Google Play Core Library?